# Using SqlDBType.Decimal in Prepared Statement C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

am using a Prepared Statement in C#.

```
 SqlCommand inscommand = new SqlCommand(supInsert, connection);
 inscommand.Parameters.Add("@ordQty", SqlDbType.Decimal,18);
 inscommand.Prepare();
 u = inscommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The above code throws below Exception:

*SqlCommand.Prepare method requires parameters of type 'Decimal' have an explicitly set Precision and Scale.*

EDIT:  How to avoid this Exception

Comment: Do you have a question? What do you find unclear about the error?

Comment: Hi Oded, Yes Am getting the above exception to set precision and scale.

Comment: And? What is not clear about the error? You need to set precision and scale.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The following would set a Decimal with Precision 18 and Scale 8 (Decimal (18,8))

```
SqlCommand insertCommand= new SqlCommand(supInsert, connection);
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ordQty", SqlDbType.Decimal,18);

insertCommand.Parameters["@ordQty"].Precision = 18;
insertCommand.Parameters["@ordQty"].Scale = 8;

insertCommand.Prepare();
u = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: For anyone struggling with this like I was, the Precision is the total number of digits including any after the decimal point. The Scale is just the number of digits after the decimal point.
So to store a 3 digit number with 1 decimal place such as  100.1  the SQL column type would need to be at least decimal(4,1) and this would gives a Precision of 4 and Scale of 1 to be used in the C# in this answer.

Answer (score 13):

As the exception pointed out, you have to explicitly set the `SqlParameter.Precision` and `SqlParameter.Scale` properties in order to use the `decimal` type as a parameter.

Let's say your SQL field is of type `decimal(18,8)`. The way to do this inline is to use brace-initialization for your SqlParameter while adding it to the `SqlParameterCollection`, as follows:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ordGty", SqlDbType.Decimal) {
    Precision = 18, Scale = 8 });
```

You can also do

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ordGty", SqlDbType.Decimal) {
    Precision = 18, Scale = 8}).Value = 0.4m; // or whatever
```

to add the value, if you need one. You could even do

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ordGty", SqlDbType.Decimal) {
    Precision = 18, Scale = 8, Value = 0.4m /* or whatever */});
```

if you prefer. [Brace initialization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171710/creating-object-parameters-in) is really powerful.

Side note: I realize that this is an old question, but I think this form is much more readable than creating the object while adding it to the list and then setting the scale and precision. For Posterity! (since this is a high-listing google search result)

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@ordQty", SqlDbType.Decimal);
parameter.Precision = 18;
parameter.Scale = 0;
parameter.Value = YOURVALUEHERE;
inscommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to explicitly define precision and scale for this parameter.

```
SqlParameter ordQty = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ordQty", SqlDbType.Decimal);
ordQty.Precision = x; //Replace x with what you expect in Sql Sp
ordQty.Scale = y; //Replace y with what you expect in Sql Sp
ordQty.Value = 18; //Set value here
inscommand.Parameters.Add(ordQty);
```