# ASP.NET & SQL Server : Incorrect syntax near '?'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, opayo

I am receiving an error

> Incorrect syntax near ?

when trying to use a update query function. The code is from SagePay `http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/12136/download-document/DotNetkit%201.2.6.7%20-%202014-08-14.zip?token=BJFwtM7qNnnm5ZCc_l_dOhq4INB0cQTPCxCd5JOpeh4` and relates to their server InFrame implementation.

As far as I can see the order is being passed correctly, and the list of fields, match the database, just not understanding why I am seeing this error. The code was originally created for MySQL but have had to adapt to SQL Server.

I've tried debugging, but cannot actually see what is being committed to the SQL Server from `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` any help would be much appreciated, here is the code:

```
private static readonly List<String> FieldNames = new List<String>
{
    VendorTxCodeField, AddressResultField, AddressStatusField, AmountField, AvsCv2Field, BankAuthCodeField, BasketField,
    BillingFirstnamesField, BillingSurnameField, BillingPhoneField, BillingAddress1Field, BillingAddress2Field, BillingCityField, 
    BillingPostCodeField, BillingStateField, BillingCountryField, DeclineCodeField, DeliveryFirstnamesField, DeliverySurnameField, DeliveryPhoneField, 
    DeliveryAddress1Field, DeliveryAddress2Field, DeliveryCityField, DeliveryPostCodeField, DeliveryStateField, DeliveryCountryField,
    CapturedAmountField, CardTypeField, CavvField, CurrencyField, CustomerEmailField, Cv2ResultField, ExpiryDateField, FraudResponseField,
    GiftAidField, Last4DigitsField, LastUpdatedField, PayerIdField, PayerStatusField, PostCodeResultField, 
    RelatedVendorTxCodeField, SecurityKeyField, StatusField, StatusMessageField, SurchargeField, ThreeDSecureStatusField,
    TransactionTypeField, TxAuthNoField, TokenIdField, VpsTxIdField
};    

public static bool UpdateOrder(Order order, string vendorTxCode)
{
    var result = false;

    SqlConnection conn = null;

    try
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        var cmd = new SqlCommand
        {
            Connection = conn, CommandText = "UPDATE Orders SET " + string.Join(",", FieldNames.Select(field => field + "=?" + field).ToList()) + " WHERE " + VendorTxCodeField + " =?" + VendorTxCodeField
        };

        cmd.Prepare();

        AddOrderParameters(cmd, order);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        result = true;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private static void AddOrderParameters(SqlCommand command, Order order)
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(VendorTxCodeField, order.VendorTxCode);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(AddressResultField, order.AddressResult);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(AddressStatusField, order.AddressStatus);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(AmountField, order.Amount);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(AvsCv2Field, order.AvsCv2);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(BankAuthCodeField, order.BankAuthCode);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(BasketField, order.Basket);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(BillingAddress1Field, order.BillingAddress1);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(BillingAddress2Field, order.BillingAddress2);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(BillingCityField, order.BillingCity);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(BillingCountryField, order.BillingCountry);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(BillingFirstnamesField, order.BillingFirstnames);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(BillingPhoneField, order.BillingPhone);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(BillingPostCodeField, order.BillingPostCode);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(BillingStateField, order.BillingState);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(BillingSurnameField, order.BillingSurname);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(CapturedAmountField, order.CapturedAmount);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(CardTypeField, order.CardType);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(CavvField, order.Cavv);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(CurrencyField, order.Currency);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(CustomerEmailField, order.CustomerEmail);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(Cv2ResultField, order.Cv2Result);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DeclineCodeField, order.DeclineCode);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DeliveryAddress1Field, order.DeliveryAddress1);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DeliveryAddress2Field, order.DeliveryAddress2);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DeliveryCityField, order.DeliveryCity);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DeliveryCountryField, order.DeliveryCountry);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DeliveryFirstnamesField, order.DeliveryFirstnames);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DeliveryPhoneField, order.DeliveryPhone);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DeliveryPostCodeField, order.DeliveryPostCode);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DeliveryStateField, order.DeliveryState);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DeliverySurnameField, order.DeliverySurname);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(ExpiryDateField, order.ExpiryDate);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(FraudResponseField, order.FraudResponse);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(GiftAidField, order.GiftAid);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(Last4DigitsField, order.Last4Digits);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(LastUpdatedField, order.LastUpdated);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(PayerIdField, order.PayerId);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(PayerStatusField, order.PayerStatus);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(PostCodeResultField, order.PostCodeResult);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(RelatedVendorTxCodeField, order.RelatedVendorTxCode);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(SecurityKeyField, order.SecurityKey);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(StatusField, order.Status);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(StatusMessageField, order.StatusMessage);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(SurchargeField, order.Surcharge);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(ThreeDSecureStatusField, order.ThreeDSecureStatus);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(TokenIdField, order.TokenId);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(TransactionTypeField, order.TransactionType);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(TxAuthNoField, order.TxAuthNo);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(VpsTxIdField, order.VpsTxId);
 }
```

Comment: You are ending up with a statement like `SET VendorTxCodeField = ?VendorTxCodeField`, which is not valid. Change `?` to `@` so you end up with `SET VendorTxCodeField = @VendorTxCodeField`. You should also use [AddWithValue with caution](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), explicitly stating the type (e.g. `Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Some Parameter")`, although more verbose, is much safer.

Comment: I am now getting the following error `The parameterized query '(@VendorTxCode nvarchar(36),@AddressResult nvarchar(4000),@Addre' expects the parameter '@AddressResult', which was not supplied."` so am I correct in saying I need to amend `AddOrderParameters` with the appropriate data types?

Comment: The reason for this is usually a null parameter value, if you do something like `Parameters.AddWithValue("@Test", null)`, `@Test` is not acutally passed to the command. You need to check for null parameters, and probably do something like "Parameters.Add("@Test", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = String.IsNullOrEmpty(order.AddressResult) ? DbNull.Value : (object)order.AddressResult;` or add an empty string if this is what is required.

Comment: Some of the values are null, there are update query is ran twice, the 1st adds billing details, but doesn't have the transaction results, hence the error, thank you.

Comment: I have started to modify like so `command.Parameters.Add("@"+ VendorTxCodeField, SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(order.VendorTxCode) ? null : (object)order.VendorTxCode;` and that error has disappeared, so thank you, but how do I check the amount as that is a Decimal (19,2) ?

Comment: decimal is a value type so won't be null,

Comment: But as I'm declaring data types, how do I specify 19 with 2 decimal places when using 'Parameters.Add' because SqlDbType.Decimal, 19) will truncate the decimal places?

Comment: [This answer should help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8758279/1048425)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64016/discussion-between-iggyweb-and-garethd).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `@` for sql-parameters. Maybe this fixes your issue although i must admit that i don't understand the query because the column-names are the same as the values. However ...

```
string sql = @"UPDATE Orders SET {0}
               Where {1}=@{1};";
sql = string.Format(sql
    , string.Join(",", FieldNames.Select(field => string.Format("{0}=@{0}", field)))
    , VendorTxCodeField);

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < FieldNames.Count; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(FieldNames[i], FieldNames[i]);
    }
    // open connection and execute the command...
}
```

Comment: The code is from SagePay I'm just trying to get it to work with our SQL Server, I'll try your suggestion as soon as I get out of this meeting, thank you.